# run powershell script with C# System.Diagnostics.Process , powershell script sees no arguments

Tags: c#, powershell, external-process

I decided to use System.Diagnostics.Process to run a powershell script just because it seemed simple,I didn't care about the result output, and I wanted the user to be able to see what was running

```
Process process = new Process();

Process.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe"
Process.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("-executionpolicy unrestricted -noexit \"{0}\" -XmlConfigFile {1}",scriptname, configFile);
process.Start();
```

When I run this the script sees no arguments. Due to the noexit I can test $args and $MyInvocation at the end. No arguments. If I run it in cmd.exe it works, If I leave off the {1} it complains about -XmlConfigFile missing an argument.

edit: turns out It was my fault I was running nested powershell sessions to deal with forcing powershell to use 4.0 and only passing along args which doesn't include arguments in $psboundparameters.

Comment: Have you double checked that the result of the `String.Format` is what you expect it to be?

Comment: Have you used something like Process Explorer to look at the command line as seen by the underlying process launch?

Comment: I've double checked the args with a MessageBox, and then pasted it into cmd.exe after a "powershell.exe " and it saw the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, as it works for me:

```
Process.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("-executionpolicy unrestricted 
-noexit -file \"{0}\" -XmlConfigFile {1}",scriptname, configFile);
```

Though I dont know what -XmlConfigFile does. As it seems to be no valid argument:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx

So you may remove it for a start.

Comment: -XmlConfigFile is an argument of my script file not of powershell